# Optimize storage and bandwith use in a chat app using Realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im developing a chat app with Realtime Database as backend, and this is the way i save the data into the DB:

[image]

I identify each message with the full uid of the user sending it.
Do you think is this necessary, or can i only save the first 10 characters (for example) of the uid in order to reduce bytes? my concern is if in some moment 2 diferent users will have the same 10 first  characters

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the first 10 characters of a UID are going to be unique, so using those as an identifier is not a great idea.

If you want to use shorter IDs, the two first options that come to mind are:

- Create your own identifier for each user in the room, for example by giving them a sequential ID, and then store that.
- Use an actual hash function to determine a shorter unique ID for each user. While there is still a chance of collisions (multiple users getting the same ID), the chances are likely smaller then when you just take the first 10 characters.

In all cases, I'd highly recommend calculating the cost savings that you'll accomplish with this though. Message length is more typically the dominant factor in the size of each message.